# 'XGBModel' object has no attribute 'feature_types'

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, pickle, xgboost

I have an xgboost model saved in my databricks directory.

I call the model by the commands below

```
model = pickle.load(open('/.../model.pkl', 'rb'))
model.predict_proba(df[features])
```

The model has been running for sometime with the above commands but I now get an error saying

```
'XGBModel' object has no attribute 'feature_types'
```

I tried specifying the version of the xgboost library installation but that does not work.

What could be the issue?